# if-else logic issue in java 8 stream for filter

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Question:

Give a `ArrayList` of `Player`s -  `List<Player>`. Take a `Player` POJO with `String Name`, `int age`, and `int runs`. Build a list using `list.add`.

Find the first player whose age is less than 30 and Runs greater than 5000 and print the name. or else print "No player selected for world cup"

POJO class:

```java
public class Player {
    String name;
    int age;
    int runs;
    
    public Player(String name, int age, int runs) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.runs = runs;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Player [name=" + name + "]";
    }
}
```

Logic:

```java
List<Player> players = Arrays.asList(
    new Player("Sachin",45,10252),
    new Player("Virat",29,7000),
    new Player("Dhoni",38,4000),
    new Player("Yuvraj",29,5500)
);

List<Player> filtered = players.stream()
    .filter(i -> i.runs > 5000 && i.age > 50)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

if(filtered == null) {
    System.out.println("No Player selected for World Cup");
} else {
    System.out.println(filtered);
}
```

here the if part is not executing, else is running fine for valid conditions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using `collect(Collection.toList())` the list returned is never null. If there's a filter that no arguments match, the list is empty. You should change your condition to `filtered.isEmpty()`.

Note, however, that the list can be null in a stream.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
    List<Player> players = Arrays.asList(new Player("Sachin", 45, 10252), new Player("Virat", 29, 7000), new Player("Dhoni", 38, 4000),
            new Player("Viraaat", 28, 7000), new Player("Yuvraj", 29, 5500));
    List<Player> filtered = players.stream().filter(i -> i.runs > 5000 && i.age < 30).collect(Collectors.toList());
    if (filtered.isEmpty())
        System.out.println("No Player selected for World Cup");
    else
        System.out.println(filtered.get(0));
```

Answer (score 1):

The `collect()` statement will return an array object. You have to check if that array is empty or not.

Also, if you like, you can use the `.anyMatch()` statement to get a boolean about if there is any match with your `filter()`.

```java
List<Player> players = Arrays.asList(
    new Player("Sachin",45,10252),
    new Player("Virat",29,7000),
    new Player("Dhoni",38,4000),
    new Player("Yuvraj",29,5500)
);

boolean hasPlayers = players.stream().anyMatch(i -> i.runs > 5000 && i.age > 50);
if(!hasPlayers) {
    System.out.println("No Player selected for World Cup");
}
```

Comment: But then you have to re-run the filter in case some players match it.

Comment: @EldarB. correct, the usage of this anyMatch depends on the requirements you have.